# How to get popcorn js to work in ie 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, popcornjs

I am trying to get popcorn js to work with ie8 in order to set cues for javascript actions. Has anyone ever seen a working example? I have been searching the web and every ie 8 demo i could find did not work.

Is there a special player i need to use for ie 8?

Thanks in advance for any advice

regards

wolf

Comment: isnt popcorn for <video>?

Comment: yes but it sais in the docu that it has ie 8 support
http://popcornjs.org/download

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the Github code repository, I notice that there's [an `ie8` folder](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/tree/master/ie8), containing IE8-specific code, such as *popcorn.ie8.js*.

I guess that would be what you need.

Comment: i already looked at that and tried it but it did not work in ie 8 
i will post a link from the test page here shortly

Comment: i am still unable to get it to work. apearantly nobody has gotten this to work yet?